# Lumen Eloquent Relations

Tags: eloquent, lumen

**UPDATE**

My approach is to receive something equal to a simpel mysql join. I want all entries from tabel tx with project_id = x joined with txevent on tx.id = txevent.tx_id.

I´m using lumen 5.5

**UPDATE 2**

The following raw sql will do exactly what I want:

```
$rawTx = DB::>table('tx')
            ->join('txevent', 'txevent.tx_id', '=', 'tx.id')
            ->where('tx.project_id', $request->get('project_id'))
            ->where('txevent.short_id', $request->get('short_id'))
            ->get();
```

Isn´t it possible to achieve the same with relations?

**END UPDATE**

I´ve got 2 tables `tx` and `txevent`:

**tx:**

```
id, int, autoincrement
project_id, int
```

**txevent:**

```
id, int, autoincrement
tx_id, int, fk(tx.id)
shortnumber, char
```

**in tx.php I´ve got the following method:**

```
public function txeventWithShortnumber($shortnumber)
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Txevent')->where('shortnumber', $shortnumber)->first();
}
```

**in TxController.php I´ll do:**

```
$tx = Tx::where('project_id', $request->get('project_id'))->txeventWithShortnumber($request->get('shortnumber'))->get();
```

**as result I get the following error message:**

(1/1) BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::txeventWithShortnumber()

in Builder.php line 2483

Can someone tell me what I´m doing wrong?

Comment: Can there be multiple `txevent` against one `tx` irrespective of shortnumber ?

Comment: yes, 1 tx can have n txevent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to do it this way:

In `Tx.php`

```php
public function txEvents()
{
  return $this->hasMany(TxEvent::class);
}

public function txeventWithShortnumber($shortNumber)
{
  return $this->txEvents->first(function($txevent) use ($shortNumber) {
     return $txevent->shortnumber == $shortNumber;
  });
}
```

In controller:

```php
$tx = Tx::where('project_id', $request->get('project_id'))->get();

// attach shortNumber event
$tx->map(function($t) use ($request) {
    $t->eventWithShortNumber = $t->txeventWithShortnumber($request->get('shortnumber'));
});
```

`$tx` variable will now hold txEvents with the given short number as well.

I am not sure if you can dynamically pass condition to an eloquent relationship.

Comment: you code results in: 
(1/1) ErrorException
Undefined variable: tx

in TxController.php line 55

Comment: As I´m quite new to the relations I maybe missunderstand the whole thing. My goal is to achieve a result like a normal join in sql. return all from tx with the corresponding data from txevent where txevent.tx_id = tx.id. refering to the guides I found this is what I ended up with.

Comment: Updated my answer, there was a typo, it should work now.

Comment: ends up with: 
(1/1) FatalThrowableError
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\request()

in TxController.php line 55

Comment: I updated my answer. Looks like you're using old laravel version. Give it a try now.

Comment: technically the problem seems to be solved, but as the the result is still an error so this might not be an operable solution: (1/1) FatalErrorException
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 12528360 bytes) - the database contains around 4k entrys for the given project but only one with the specific shortnumber so the result shouldn´t exhaust the memory :-/